# Не удалось найти часть пути. An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

Вылетает такое исключение в методе

```
public Stream GetFileData(AppFileInfo fileInfo)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(TestConfigPath, fileInfo.RelativePath, fileInfo.FileName);
    return File.OpenRead(path);
}
```

Причем в исключении указан путь:

> D:\CS\BCDemo.sln

А мне необходим путь

> D:\TestRemoteConfigsCS\BCDemo\CS\BCDemo.sln path = CS\BCDemo.sln

а должно быть

> D:\TestRemoteConfigsCS\BCDemo\CS\BCDemo.sln

```
private string TestConfigPath
{
    get
    {
        return Path.Combine(@"D:\TestRemoteConfigs", _configInfo.Url); } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы подробнее описать суть вопроса? *Причем пишет путь "D:\CS\BCDemo.sln"* - куда и кто пишет, где Вы это видите? *А мне необходим путь* - где необходим?

Comment: Прошу прощения за глупое описание. Мне необходимо прочесть некий файл, путь которого комбинируется, и передать его Stream. При попытке это сделать появляется исключение. При проходе отладчиком отдельно по всем переменным все в порядке, но в итоге File.OpenRead принимает параметр path не в корректном виде, не учитывая свойство TestConfigPath

Comment: Если просто посмотреть перед тем как записывать `path` переменную `TestConfigPath` - что возвращает?

Comment: возвращает D:\TestRemoteConfigsCS\BCDemo\

Comment: заменил как Вы предложили, результат тот же

Comment: а что в `fileInfo.RelativePath` и в `fileInfo.FileName` по отдельности?

Comment: CS и BCDemo.sln соответственно

Comment: Набросал тест, на основании предоставленных Вами данных получил в результате: **D:\TestRemoteConfigsCS\BCDemo\CS\BCDemo.sln**. Попробуйте пошагово пройти в методе `GetFileData`, причем каждое соединение `Path.Combine` вынесите в отдельную переменную, чтобы уже 100% быть уверенным.

Comment: Попробовал, результат тот же. Может ли это быть связано с тем, что из разных потоков в проге обращение к переменной? хотя замечено не было

Comment: да, возможно в потоках дело. Попробуйте не использовать многопоточность, отладьте в одном потоке, если проблема уйдет - смотрите, что не так с потоками.

Comment: Спасибо за попытку помочь. Проблемой оказался лишний слеш, который появлялся немного раньше в коде.

Comment: Ах вот оно что! А я голову ломал, как же так происходит, тест набросал и не мог понять, почему у Вас не так!